# Searching a string in stored procedure definitions fails when the definition is too long

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I run this query to find references to `MyTable` in the stored procedures in my data base:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION, ROUTINE_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%MyTable%'
```

However, I did not find anything, the problem is that ROUTINE_DEFINITION is limited to 4000 characters and the SP that operated on `MyTable` was longer. Using `View Dependencies` on the table did not work.

My question: Is there any way to access to the whole stored procedure definition when it is longer than 4.000 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with `sysobjects` and `syscomments`

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.[NAME], C.[text]
FROM sysobjects O
JOIN syscomments C ON C.id = O.id
WHERE C.[text] LIKE '%MyTable%'
```

**UPDATE:** As suggested by [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517596/searching-a-string-in-stored-procedure-definitions-fails-when-the-definition-is/44517851#comment76029602_44517851), you can use [sys.procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-procedures-transact-sql) and [sys.sql_modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql)  to get the definitions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.[name], m.[definition]
FROM sys.procedures p 
JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.[object_id] = p.[object_id]
WHERE m.[definition] LIKE '%MyTable%'
```

Comment: Or even better: use `sys.procedures` and `sys.sql_modules` (those more focused views in the `sys` schema are the preferred ways of accessing the SQL Server system catalog views as of SQL Server 2005 and newer)

Comment: @marc_s : Updated the answer with the `sys.procedures` and `sys.sql_modules`.